# Simple Injector Parameter appended to Factory

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

For brevity, I'll use some short and generalized naming conventions.  If I have:

```
public class Factory : IFactory
{
     private readonly string dbConnection;
     public Factory(string dbConnection)
     {
          this.dbConnection= dbConnection;
     }

     public IDataContext Create() => new DataContext(dbConnection);
}
```

The `Factory` class has a field, which is being set by the Constructor.  How does Simple Injector support the passing of that parameter?  If you implement:

```
public class Service
{
     private IFactory Factory { get; }
     public Service(IFactory factory)
     {
         Factory = factory;
     }

     public void Save()
     {
          using(var context = Factory.Create())
              context.Insert(...);
     }
}
```

The parameter is never actually passed to or through the `Factory` when it is initialized or instantiated. When you register the dependencies, it doesn't look it is possible:

```
ContainerFactory.Register<IFactory, Factory>(Lifestyle.Transient);
```

I was looking into the `IEventHandler` interface, that is apart of Simple Injector which looks like it would address this issue, but is that how you're supposed to pass a parameter in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

```
container.RegisterSingleton<IFactory>(new Factory("constr"));
```

Comment: I'll take a look.